# ASP Classic + IIS7 issues

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I've just enabled ASP Classic on an IIS7 install on Windows 2008 and tried to move an ASP application previously running on IIS6 on Windows 2003 to the IIS7 server. I'm getting the following error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' 
Server.CreateObject Failed 
/Includes/SessionInclude.asp, line 3 
800401f3
```

SessionInclude.asp line 3 is:

```
set Session = server.CreateObject("SessionMgr.Session2")
```

My first thoughts were that there were some permission issues or a DLL needed registering, but I would think that the SessionMgr being a basic function should already be registered as a default?
Has someone ran into this issue before and would be able to shed some light on this issue? or the DLL I need to register?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not using something that is built-in to ASP (hence the need to instantiate it like so). It is a replacement for the default ASP `Session` object that permits sharing of session state with ASP.NET. You apparently need to find the SessionMgr.dll (or SessionManager.dll) file and register it on the new server.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

Comment: Good o'l DLL hell...

Comment: Managed to locate and register the appropriate DLLs and switched IIS to run in a 32-bit application pool. Have issues with ODBC drivers not being found even though they are there but that's another issue that I will through. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of service! Don't forget to click the check mark next to my answer to select it as the solution! (we both get 'reputation' for that)

Comment: @Mark Henderson: We forget at times how easy we have it now, in the .NET world, I think! hehe

Answer (score 1):

Can you try configuring the WebSite in Classic .NET AppPool and confirm if that helps. I would also run Process Monitor and check if there are any ACCESS DENIED or FAILURES.

Good thing is you also have Failed Request Tracing to assist you troubleshoot the issue.